# Oracle Apex Comparing multiple numbers in a Chart

Tags: sql, oracle, charts, plsql, oracle-apex

I have two tables which contain multiple years in them. What I would like to do is produce a report/chart that counts the numbers of rows where the years are not all the same.

I have copied an example below of the tables. (In my actual tables the years range from 1-10 , however for this example I have shortened it to 3)

[image]

So I ideally want a Pie Chart which counts the amount of time in table 1 and then table 2, that all 3 years do not match in a row. Which in the example below **Table 1** would count 1 and **Table 2** would count 2.

Using the following code gets the correct total;

```
Select COUNT(table_ID) Example
FROM Table1
WHERE Year_1 != ANY (year_2, year_3)
OR Year_2 != ANY (year_3)

Select COUNT(table_ID) Example
FROM Table2
WHERE Year_1 != ANY (year_2, year_3)
OR Year_2 != ANY (year_3)
```

However if I try merging these queries for a report it doesn't seem to work, and a Pie Chart needs to have a Group BY and I don't have anything to group them by.
The Pie Chart would then look like;

[image]

Comment: If you have any question please ask. It is an extremely specific question and I have rambled a bit but if anything doesn't make sense please ask so that I can clear it up. Thanks